# Postgres SQL COPY taking forever?

Tags: sql, postgresql, copy, psql

I'm fairly new to psql. I'm trying to copy a approximately 1 million rows from a text file into a table.

I try and use `COPY` and I get the error message:

> ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
>
> HINT:  Anyone COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.

I can't change my user status. So I've tried `\copy`. My command looks like this in the psql shell:

```
\copy my_table FROM 'C:/Users/Owner/Documents/myfile.txt' WITH DELIMITER '|' ;
```

When I hit enter nothing seems to happen. No error messages or any signs of anything.

My data file looks like this:

```
54548800|2032101|KH|1425|ABC
```

Does it just take a very long time or have I done something wrong?
Any Help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Copy several rows into a different file and run the command with a smaller file -- you'll have a better idea if it's copying or not.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @JuliaLeder . I can get the first 5 rows to copy.
I'm assuming this means there is bad data that needs to be cleaned?

Comment: If there are no errors and the small file is loading then it might be just taking a while because of the number of rows.  I'd say just let it run and see what happens.